# Como sacar muestras de filas consecutivas de un dataset en python?

Tags: split, machine-learning, dataset

Tengo un dataset para clasificar una serie de tiempo en una clase que indique si sube o baja segun el resultado de la fila anterior. Por esta razón necesito sacar muestras aleatorias de un dataset que tengan filas consecutivas para una extension dada. Necesito ayuda sobre como hacer esto.

El data set es el siguiente:
Tiene una columna close con el precio de una accion y 3 rezagos de dias anteriores

Comment: Y donde esta el código que tienes para el dataset?

Comment: Hola Manuela, bienvenida, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar).
Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Manuela_Piedrahita, desconosco los datos que posees, pero puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
!pip install yfinance # Si estas trabajando con google colab

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import yfinance as yf


#   Par es Euro vs Dolar americano
#   Tomamos los datos diarios del movimiento EUR/USD del año 2019
datos = yf.download('EURUSD=X', start='2019-01-02', end='2019-12-31')

# Convertimos el indice de numpy.array a datetime
datos.index = pd.to_datetime(datos.index)

# Reiniciar el index, convierte el index (DateTime) en un index (Integer)
datos_close = datos['Close'].reset_index()

# Re-nombramos las columnas (OPCIONAL)
datos_close.columns = ['Fecha','Cierre']


#================================================================
# Tu pregunta...
#================================================================
# Saber si el activo sube o baja con respeto al día anterior: shift(-1)
#sub_baj = (datos_close.shift(-1) - datos_close).dropna()
sub_baj = (datos_close.shift(-1) - datos_close)['Cierre'].shift(1).dropna().map(lambda x: -1 if x < 0 else ( 1 if x > 0 else 0 ) )

# Obtienes 
'''
1     -1
2      1
3      1
4      1
5     -1
      ..
253    1
254   -1
255    1
256    1
257    1
'''

### Agregamos las subidas y las bajadas a una columna llamada "sub_baj"
#   del dataframe «datos_close»
datos_close['sub_baj'] = sub_baj

'''
         Fecha    Cierre  sub_baj
0   2019-01-02  1.146171      NaN        <-- Esta parte es importante
1   2019-01-03  1.131811     -1.0            la fecha 2019-01-02 no tiene
2   2019-01-04  1.139108      1.0            datos, por que se desconoce
3   2019-01-07  1.141044      1.0            cual era el valor anterior.
4   2019-01-08  1.147974      1.0            No se sabe si subió o bajo.
..         ...       ...      ...
253 2019-12-24  1.109385      1.0
254 2019-12-25  1.109016     -1.0
255 2019-12-26  1.109545      1.0
256 2019-12-27  1.110112      1.0
257 2019-12-30  1.118230      1.0
'''


### Si quieres comparar el valor actual y saber si sube o baja con respecto a
# tres dias atras, debes usar:  shift(-3)
#sub_baj = (datos_close.shift(-3) - datos_close)['Cierre'].shift(3).dropna().map(lambda x: -1 if x < 0 else ( 1 if x > 0 else 0 ) )


#================================================================
# Tu otra pregunta...
#================================================================
### Extraer muestras aleatorias
#   Agrupamos los datos, la variable «extencion_de_la_agrupacion»
#   se encarga de hacer segmentos seguidos en el dataframe
extencion_de_la_agrupacion = 3

# Crea grupos (en este caso de 3 en 3) y muestra 
grupos =  datos_close.groupby(datos_close.index // extencion_de_la_agrupacion) \
                                  .agg({'Fecha': lambda x: x.head(extencion_de_la_agrupacion).max(),
                                        'Cierre':lambda x: x.head(extencion_de_la_agrupacion).max(),
                                        'sub_baj':lambda x: x.head(extencion_de_la_agrupacion).max()})
'''
        Fecha    Cierre  sub_baj
0  2019-01-04  1.146171      1.0       Fijate que las fechas van de 3
1  2019-01-09  1.147974      1.0       en 3. 
2  2019-01-14  1.155495      1.0       extencion_de_la_agrupacion = 3
3  2019-01-17  1.147289      1.0
4  2019-01-22  1.139264      1.0       Ten en cuenta que el mercado de
..        ...       ...      ...       Forex no abre los fines de semana.
81 2019-12-12  1.113586      1.0       En esos casos el conteo es cada 5.
82 2019-12-17  1.118606      1.0
83 2019-12-20  1.115138      1.0
84 2019-12-25  1.109385      1.0
85 2019-12-30  1.118230      1.0
'''

# Seleccionas 20 muestras al azar del dataframe anterior
muestras_aleatorias = grupos.sample(n=20)

'''
        Fecha    Cierre  sub_baj
56 2019-08-29  1.110371     -1.0
31 2019-05-15  1.123646      1.0
55 2019-08-26  1.114305      1.0
82 2019-12-17  1.118606      1.0
83 2019-12-20  1.115138      1.0
44 2019-07-10  1.122738     -1.0
50 2019-08-05  1.110803      1.0
85 2019-12-30  1.118230      1.0
72 2019-11-05  1.116657      1.0
74 2019-11-13  1.103546      1.0
9  2019-02-12  1.133877     -1.0
58 2019-09-06  1.103631      1.0
12 2019-02-25  1.134636      1.0
42 2019-07-02  1.137294     -1.0
28 2019-05-02  1.121604      1.0
69 2019-10-23  1.115573      1.0
79 2019-12-04  1.108525      1.0
80 2019-12-09  1.110543      1.0
2  2019-01-14  1.155495      1.0
63 2019-09-27  1.101686      1.0
'''
```

La respuesta es muy genérica y puede estar muy lejos de lo que estas manejando, así que cualquier inquietud no dudes en escribirnos...